# school of economics/economic

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What is more natural use in English when you speak about the school where you study economy?
I heard some people say `School of economics` and in the other hand `Economic School`. What is correct? Is there any difference

Never used that in English, only in my language, so sorry if this is a stupid question but I need the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We say school of economics. The most famous one in the world being: The London School of Economics, or LSE for short.

economic school is an error.

- school of law (also law school), school of economics, school of design, etc. But very often capitals are used to refer to an actual school: 
  Rhode Island School of Design

In discussing educational institutions, school of economics is the right term. Sometimes,  you can use a noun as an adjective: law school. It depends on the discipline and the word. **It can get rather complicated.** A school of philosophy is the same as a philosophical school, but in this case does not refer to a physical place. However, a cooking school would be a physical place.